# SHOPIFY | Items added to cart, not displayed until page refresh

Tags: javascript, shopify, ajaxify

I don't really have much experience in coding, but I found a tutorial on how to add an "Add to cart" button to shopify products without entering the specific product.

Im having troubles with my cart not updating and displaying the added items without me having to refresh the page or go to another page. This applies to both collection items and featured product items.

webpage: https://www.agoodcase.dk/

This is the snippet I am using to add items to the cart

```html
<script>

/**
 * Module to ajaxify all add to cart forms on the page.
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2015 Caroline Schnapp (11heavens.com)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 *
 */
Shopify.AjaxifyCart = (function($) {
  
  // Some configuration options.
  // I have separated what you will never need to change from what
  // you might change.
  
  var _config = {
    
    // What you might want to change
    addToCartBtnLabel:             'Tilføj til kurv',
    addedToCartBtnLabel:           'Tak!',
    addingToCartBtnLabel:          'Tilføjer...',
    soldOutBtnLabel:               'Udsolgt',
    howLongTillBtnReturnsToNormal: 2000, // in milliseconds.
    cartCountSelector:             '.cart-count, #cart-count a:first, #gocart p a, #cart .checkout em, .item-count',
    cartTotalSelector:             '#cart-price',
    // 'aboveForm' for top of add to cart form, 
    // 'belowForm' for below the add to cart form, and 
    // 'nextButton' for next to add to cart button.
    feedbackPosition:              'nextButton',
    
    // What you will never need to change
    addToCartBtnSelector:          '[type="submit"]',
    addToCartFormSelector:         'form[action="/cart/add"]',
    shopifyAjaxAddURL:             '/cart/add.js',
    shopifyAjaxCartURL:            '/cart.js'
  };
  
  // We need some feedback when adding an item to the cart.
  // Here it is.  
  var _showFeedback = function(success, html, $addToCartForm) {
    $('.ajaxified-cart-feedback').remove();
    var feedback = '<p class="ajaxified-cart-feedback ' + success + '">' + html + '</p>';
    switch (_config.feedbackPosition) {
      case 'aboveForm':
        $addToCartForm.before(feedback);
        break;
      case 'belowForm':
        $addToCartForm.after(feedback);
        break;
      case 'nextButton':
      default:
        $addToCartForm.find(_config.addToCartBtnSelector).after(feedback);
        break;   
    }
    // If you use animate.css
    // $('.ajaxified-cart-feedback').addClass('animated bounceInDown');
    $('.ajaxified-cart-feedback').slideDown();
  };
  var _setText = function($button, label) {
    if ($button.children().length) {
      $button.children().each(function() {
        if ($.trim($(this).text()) !== '') {
          $(this).text(label);
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      $button.val(label).text(label);
    }
  };
  var _init = function() {   
    $(document).ready(function() { 
      $(_config.addToCartFormSelector).submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $addToCartForm = $(this);
        var $addToCartBtn = $addToCartForm.find(_config.addToCartBtnSelector);
        _setText($addToCartBtn, _config.addingToCartBtnLabel);
        $addToCartBtn.addClass('disabled').prop('disabled', true);
        // Add to cart.
        $.ajax({
          url: _config.shopifyAjaxAddURL,
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'post',
          data: $addToCartForm.serialize(),
          success: function(itemData) {
            // Re-enable add to cart button.
            $addToCartBtn.addClass('inverted');
            _setText($addToCartBtn, _config.addedToCartBtnLabel);
            _showFeedback('success','<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Tilføjet til kurven! <a href="/cart">Gå til kassen?</a>',$addToCartForm);
            window.setTimeout(function(){
              $addToCartBtn.prop('disabled', false).removeClass('disabled').removeClass('inverted');
              _setText($addToCartBtn,_config.addToCartBtnLabel);
            }, _config.howLongTillBtnReturnsToNormal);
            // Update cart count and show cart link.
            $.getJSON(_config.shopifyAjaxCartURL, function(cart) {
              if (_config.cartCountSelector && $(_config.cartCountSelector).length()) {
                var value = $(_config.cartCountSelector).html() || '0';
                $(_config.cartCountSelector).html(value.replace(/[0-9]+/,cart.item_count)).removeClass('hidden-count');
              }
              if (_config.cartTotalSelector && $(_config.cartTotalSelector).length()) {
                if (typeof Currency !== 'undefined' && typeof Currency.moneyFormats !== 'undefined') {
                  var newCurrency = '';
                  if ($('[name="currencies"]').length()) {
                    newCurrency = $('[name="currencies"]').val();
                  }
                  else if ($('#currencies span.selected').length()) {
                    newCurrency = $('#currencies span.selected').attr('data-currency');
                  }
                  if (newCurrency) {
                    $(_config.cartTotalSelector).html('<span class=money>' + Shopify.formatMoney(Currency.convert(cart.total_price, "{{ shop.currency }}", newCurrency), Currency.money_format[newCurrency]) + '</span>');
                  } 
                  else {
                    $(_config.cartTotalSelector).html(Shopify.formatMoney(cart.total_price, "{{ shop.money_format | remove: "'" | remove: '"' }}"));
                  }
                }
                else {
                  $(_config.cartTotalSelector).html(Shopify.formatMoney(cart.total_price, "{{ shop.money_format | remove: "'" | remove: '"' }}"));
                }
              };
            });        
          }, 
          error: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
            var response = eval('(' + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ')');
            response = response.description;
            if (response.slice(0,4) === 'All ') {
              _showFeedback('error', response.replace('All 1 ', 'All '), $addToCartForm);
              $addToCartBtn.prop('disabled', false);
              _setText($addToCartBtn, _config.soldOutBtnLabel);
              $addToCartBtn.prop('disabled',true);
            }
            else {
              _showFeedback('error', '<i class="fa fa-warning"></i> ' + response, $addToCartForm);
              $addToCartBtn.prop('disabled', false).removeClass('disabled');
              _setText($addToCartBtn, _config.addToCartBtnLabel);
            }
          }
        });   
        return false;    
      });
    });
  };
  return {
    init: function(params) {
        // Configuration
        params = params || {};
        // Merging with defaults.
        $.extend(_config, params);
        // Action
        $(function() {
          _init();
        });
    },    
    getConfig: function() {
      return _config;
    }
  }  
})(jQuery);

Shopify.AjaxifyCart.init();

</script>

{% comment %}
  If you want to animate your feedback message.
{% endcomment %}

{% comment %}
{{ '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.1.0/animate.min.css' | stylesheet_tag }}
{% endcomment %}

{{ '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css' | stylesheet_tag }}

<style>
.ajaxified-cart-feedback {
  display: block;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-size: 90%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.ajaxified-cart-feedback.success { 
  color: #3D9970;
}
.ajaxified-cart-feedback.error { 
  color: #FF4136; 
} 
.ajaxified-cart-feedback a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
</style>
```

My button looks like this:

```html
<form method="post" action="/cart/add">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.variants.first.id }}" />
  <input type="submit" value="Tilføj til kurv" class="btn"/>
</form>
```

`

`

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: You need to check the website, there are liquid errors, and also need to update this snippet according to your needs, so I think you need to consult with professional regarding for paid help